# "Jenkins + Selenium Grid + Maven" ERROR: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

I am using Jenkins with Selenium Grid. I do not launch my hub & node through command line, but totally through Jenkins UI - this is one of the reasons **I am desperate for a solution through UI config** instead of command line solutions. 
I can see my node as running with "JVM Options" as "`webdriver.ie.driver=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`" . I have ensured my "IEDriverServer.exe" is stored at this folder.

Here's the image with config of my grid -
[Grid Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTwSK.png)

I have used 64-bit IEDriverServer (version 3.150.1) 
Selenium Grid version 3.141.59

My code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.XP);
capabilities.setVersion("11");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

For job configuration, under "Build Environment", I have set "Goal and options" as "`clean test`" since this is a maven project.

Everytime I build this job, I get this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Unable to create new service: InternetExplorerDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WINDOWS-JENKINS', ip: '10.162.0.5', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 344 milliseconds
    at qa.BH.Setup.Init(Setup.java:34)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Unable to create new service: InternetExplorerDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WINDOWS-JENKINS', ip: '10.162.0.5', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'WINDOWS-JENKINS', ip: '10.162.0.5', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I understand it is not able to correctly match IEDriver? `driver.version : unknown`

Help Please?

Comment: Any reason to see `os.name: 'Windows Server 2016'` and `os.name: 'Windows Server 2019'` in the same set of trace logs?

Comment: @DebanjanB Not sure, I am not able to figure out why the error log prints itself 2 times with such different version info...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stuck with this, here's what I had to do. Thanks to the many people whose posts allowed me to gather the root cause and the fixes.
**IE just does not work with the typical node on Jenkins when it's run as a service!** 
So, I HAD to start the agent and hub through command line.  
The agent needs to be started using JNLP. Steps are-
1. Create a node as you would normally do in Jenkins. Make sure you use the option **"launch agent by connecting it to the master"** while creating this. If the option is not visible, you need to enable a setting under **Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Agents > TCP port for inbound agents**. You can give a fixed port number here. Let's say the name given to the node by you is "NODE_01".
2. Once saved, you will be shown a page which gives the command to run this through command line. Something like `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://localhost:8080/computer/Node_01/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 30541e5f10d2b8b7054bcf3d99ef7798b9c99e698ade13444179b168cebf1b97 -workDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins"`

3. Download this "agent.jar" from here (it must be a hyperlink). 
4. Go to that folder in command prompt and run the above command.
5. Now for the hub -
6. Open another command prompt, go to the folder where you have your selenium-server-standalone jar file saved (Download now if you haven't so far) and run this - `java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub "http://localhost:4444/grid/register/"`
 Note that my IEDriverServer.exe path may be different to yours.
You are good to go now! Create a job and run it.